# What is the best way to add a title to a table?

Tags: html, semantics

Which element should I use for titles of tables, `<caption>` or `<th>`?

For example, I want to create this table :

[image]

What is better,

```
<tr><th colspan="2">Discographie</th></tr>
```

or

```
<caption style="font-weight: bold">Discographie</caption>
```

?

Comment: Go with first one. [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pUfmz/)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`th` corresponds to the title of the column, so in that case : "Album" and "Année"

W3C : "The th element represents a header cell in a table."
https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/tables/one-header/

`caption` corresponds to the title / description of the whole table, so yes, you'd better use caption for "Discographie".

W3C : "The caption element represents the title of the table that is its parent."
https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/tables/caption-summary/

Plus, it is easier to maintain as your table grows